# What does 0.f mean higher precision than 0.0f

Tags: ios, constants

Have seen some code using `0.f` as the value of some variable such as:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = animated ? 0.3f : 0.f;
```

Why not `0.0f`? Does `0.f` has some other benefit such as implying an precision higher than `0.0f`?

Comment: “Why not `0.0f`?” Yes, but why not `0.00f`? They are all literal representations of the same value.

Comment: Hi @PascalCuoq, what I mean is what precision does `0.f` imply? Sure that `0.00f` has higher precision than `0.0f` which makes a difference between them.

Comment: @congliu It doesn't have higher precision. Both numbers are equal, so they can't have different precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.f` likes `0.0f`, but it has shorter length. And for `0.3f`, it can be wrote as `.3f`. It might be helpful cause most of doc on coding style said the standard limit for code width is 80 characters ([REFER](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width)).

I think it's just a personal habits, no deep meaning as far as I know. :)

Comment: Hi @Kjuly Like your reference. Thank you :D

Comment: I don't think the ancient "80 chars per line" rule has anything to do with this question. Whenewer you start saving characters by omitting digits, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Sulthan yes you're right, that's just my guess, and it makes sense, right? Generally, for a single literal floatingpoint constant, it doesn't matter, `0.f` is totally the same with `0.0f`, it's transparent to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `0.00000f`? It's still a zero. There is no befenit involved, it's just shorter.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan Does 0.0f and 0.00000f really mean the same thing, the same precision, here in Objective-C? Because some numerical recipes emphasize on the importance of considering the precision of float type numbers, for example, when comparing values of two float numbers.

Comment: @congliu The precision is important when the number is converted into binary, not when you write it in decimal. Of course, zero is still zero in binary, decimal or hexadecimal.